# Windows Event Log Service Access Denied Issue

Tags: windows-services

I alwayse connect to internet via VPN on Win7 service pack 1, Today suudenly I got an unexpected error to start VPN, After efforts to find main problem and solutions, I found out it caused by Windows Event Log starting issue.

Everytime I manualy try to start this service it says "Access denied!".

Seeking for solution over the internet didn't help me. Some of them listed bellow:

- add authority and  give full permissions to System, network, Local for %system32\winevt and %system32\winevt\Logs directories.
- Removing %system32\winevt\Logs directory and give full permissions to new created directory.
- Deleting %system32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup and give full permissions to new directory.
- Changing authority of  log on account via Registery to NT Authority\LocalService by default and others.

But no succeed!

Is there any other efforts or you advice me to re-install Windows

Comment: What is the startup type of that service? Is it set to automatic?

Comment: Yes, It has been set to Automatic, even I try start it manualy by pressing Start button. I think it is because of my BIOS setting wich I updated it right before this problem.